# iOS Developer App Won't Launch Without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've developed an iOS app using Xcode. Previously I was able to load up this app and show it people without debugging via Xcode. I am no longer able to run the app unless initiated through Xcode. It loads up, gives a black screen, and kills the app (I can see it open in the multitask window list but can't view it).

I've checked the developer app is trusted in settings.
I've renewed the promising profile. 
I've checked the signing.

Anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: Do you have a free or paid membership of the developer program?

Comment: Currently using free.

Comment: There is a limitation on how long an app generated with a free membership will run on a device. If you delete the app from your device and reinstall it with Xcode then you should get another few days before you need to repeat the process.

Comment: Tried that, and refreshed the provisioning profile in-between.

Comment: I'm not sure then. You could try changing the bundle id or give Apple $99

Comment: Have you tried looking at the device console? There's a good chance of finding useful clues there from messages that appear when the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out this was a combination of two things; and I'll post in case anyone else has a similar problem. The profile had expired - but that wasn't my main problem. I did have a bug in some native C++ library I created (buffer overflow to be exact), but that library wasn't included in the XCode project. When it crashed inside that library it didn't generate a crash log on the device or console (very weird?).